# CsvHelper throws System.ObjectDisposedException on second iteration

Tags: c#, streamreader, csvhelper

I'm trying to write a method that will read all the CSV files from inside a ZIP file as submitted as an `IFormFile` through an `HttpRequest`.

I'm using `CsvHelper` to read the files contents using this code:

```
using (var archiveStream = zip.OpenReadStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveStream))
    {
        foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
            {
                using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(entryStream))
                {
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        using (var dataReader = new CsvDataReader(csv))
                        {
                            while (dataReader.Read())
                            {
                                object[] values = new object[dataReader.FieldCount];
                                dataReader.GetValues(values);
                                // do stuff with object[]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, on the second iteration of the `foreach` I get `System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed file.'` when it gets to `var dataReader = new CsvDataReader(csv)`.

It's not clear to me which "file" it thinks is disposed. How can I keep this stream open throughout the full loop?

*Possibly relevant information:* This is running inside a `Task<>` launched from an `ApiController`.

Comment: _"This is running inside a Task<> launched from an ApiController"_ - are you awaiting the task?

Comment: I am not, but do not want to.  The idea is that the `ApiController` receives the zip, kicks off the task, and the returns an HttpResponse to let the user know their work is underway.  But you're probably onto the root cause here.

Comment: I just confirmed that I do not get the error when awaiting the task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - This is running inside a `Task<>` launched from an `ApiController`.
> - Are you awaiting the task?
> - I am not

The request data will be automatically disposed by ASP.NET when the request processing will finish (i.e. when the action result will be executed and response will be send to the client), including the request body, resulting in the stream returned by `IFormFile.OpenReadStream` being disposed too. Since you are not awaiting the processing task the request processing can be finished before the task hence the exception.

You need either to await the task processing the stream or alternatively - download all the data (into memory or in some kind of temp file) and process it "offline" (either via task or some kind of background worker pipeline - see [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio), [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/), [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)).

Comment: Awesome.  I updated the `ApiController` to read the `IFormFile` into a `byte[]` and then use that in the task : `new ZipArchive(new MemoryStream(bytes))`